# Look of steel under a microscope

Tags: optics, material-science, microscopy

Short question: Why is it that steel looks grey/silver on a macroscopic scale, whereas under a light microscope it appears white, yellow or brownish? (C. f.
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlit_(Stahl)#/media/Datei:Perlit07.png or https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austenit_(Phase)#/media/Datei:AISI_304_-_austenitic_structure.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most metals, clean steel reflects a broad range of visible light wavelengths, meaning that it looks "silver", so to speak, under white light. If it appears as some other color, it's because colored light and/or lenses are being used or because the microscope is [deliberately designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallography#Analysis_techniques) to accentuate and distinguish precipitates, grain boundaries, phases, or dislocations, for instance. Preserving color information is generally not a priority in microscopy.

[This slideshow](https://www.georgevandervoort.com/images/Metallography-General/Color/Color_Metallography7_12_04.pdf) has dozens of such images that may be of interest, including preparation and imaging details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer